# LINQ. Why full load only the first time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, load

I have an entity `Contracts`, `ListKindWorks` and `KindWorks`.

```
public partial class Contracts
{
    public Contracts()
    {
        ListKindWorks = new HashSet<ListKindWorks>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ListKindWorks> ListKindWorks { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListKindWorks
{
    public int IdContract { get; set; }
    public int IdKindWork { get; set; }

    public virtual Contracts IdContractNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual KindWorks IdKindWorkNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class KindWorks
{
    public KindWorks()
    {
        ListKindWorks = new HashSet<ListKindWorks>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListKindWorks> ListKindWorks { get; set; }
}
```

And class `Item`

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load related elements via method `Load()`:

```
source = model.Contracts
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Id)
    .Skip(Page * Size)
    .Take(Size)
    .Select(c => new ContractTableRow
    {
        IdContract = c.Id,
        FullName = c.WorkerNavigation.FullName,
        IdWorker = c.Worker,
        ...

        // this code
        KindWork = c.ListKindWorks
        .Select(y => new Item 
        { Id = y.IdKindWork, Value = y.IdKindWorkNavigation.Short })
        .ToList(),

        Subject = c.ListSubjects
        .Select(y => new Item
        { Id = y.IdSubject, Value = y.IdSubjectNavigation.Short })
        .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

The first call of the method `Load()` (during load app) gives full elements. `KindWork` and `Subject` are not empty. But then when I change `Page`, `KindWork` and `Subject` are empty. The rest is always changing.

Why don't subsequent calls load this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable source as IQueryable so every time you use .ToList() query will be executed against database so you will get your changed data.

```
IQueryable<Contracts> source = *...* // without .ToList()
```

This will save this as a query (without data, as it is not executed yet on db)

Every time you call .ToList() EF will execute on sql.

```
var smth = source.ToList();
```

Comment: It worked. But the execution time of the method has greatly increased. No other way?

Comment: Every time you make .ToList(), query will get executed, thats why it slows down, especially if you call it too often. It looks like basic paging query, why are you calling that so often?

Comment: I need to get KindWork and Subject for each Contracts. I tried AsQueryable() into Select for KindWork and Subject and once .ToList() by the end. But time the same.

Comment: My mistake. Now I did IEnumerable<Item> for KindWork and Subject. ToList() only when need to Control.Items